As an Annual Technical Health Review what goals you would like to see and achieve from your Marketing Cloud instance?
In your opinion which should be the 3 health goals for Marketing Cloud that would be beneficial to track and strive for an organization from an Annual Technical Health Review perspective from the Salesforce team?
This is something that you have been asked by your Salesforce TAM (Technical Account Manager) so please suggest accordingly. Thanks in advance.

Is this an interview question?

I appreciate your question Jimmy, but you are the person who knows your platform best. So this list should be derived from your own experience.

Would you like to speed up your email send throughput?
Reduce number of automation runs?
Migrate your subscriber keys?

I will suggest engaging with your TAM to discuss your suggestions, and hear his recommendations. We can’t really make this list for you.
Also, how would you define “health goals” in first place?

Hello Lukas, I knew you'd be the first one to take the bullet! You're a warrior sir.
